# Are global objects guaranteed to be destructed after all thread-local-storage objects are destructed?

Tags: c++, multithreading, global-variables, standards, c++17

```
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
};

A g_a;

int main()
{
    thread([]()
    {
         thread_local A tl_a;
         exit(0);
    }).detach();
}
```

**Does the C++ standard guarantee `g_a` will be destructed after `tl_a` be destructed?**

Comment: you can check it by printing message while constructor and destructor ..

Comment: Compiler output is not the standard. No matter what the output is, I am not sure whether it is conforming to the C++ standard.

Comment: Why can't you check the standard yourself? The working draft is freely available in both PDF and HTML formats from a variety of sources.

Comment: @T.C. The standard documents is too hard for me to read. My first information source is cppreference.com, which is more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does.

Section [basic.start.term] in the language spec says

> Destructors (12.4) for initialized objects (that is, objects whose lifetime (3.8) has begun) with static storage
>   duration are called as a result of returning from main and as a result of calling std::exit (18.5). Destructors
>   for initialized objects with thread storage duration within a given thread are called as a result of returning
>   from the initial function of that thread and as a result of that thread calling std::exit. The completions
>   of the destructors for all initialized objects with thread storage duration within that thread are sequenced
>   before the initiation of the destructors of any object with static storage duration.

So the thread local variables will be destroyed before the static (global) ones.